# How can I add an href to a preexisting button so that it will scroll to an id on a webpage?

Tags: html, scroll

I keep trying things that don't work or break it in some other way.

```
<p class="text-center mt-30"><p class="text-center mt-30"><a class="btn btn-red btn-circle" href="bookAtable">Get Started</a></p>
```

I want the button to scroll the bookAtable id, but I don't know to hook up the button and the scroll function to the "Get Started" text at the same time

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to add a # before bookAtable in the href

```
<a href="#bookAtable">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a # before bookAtable, so it would look like href="#bookAtable"